# Chrome extension API method chrome.webrequest.onheadersreceived not getting the content-length in responseHeader

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to get the `content-length` in `chrome.webrequest.onheadersreceived` for `https` requests. For `http` with `localhost` however it's working fine. I have done the basic setup.

PFB manifesto file details:

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "description": "example extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "2",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "bookmarks",
    "<all_urls>",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "downloads",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

PFB background.js file contains:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (obj) {
   let iContentLength = obj.responseHeaders.filter(x => x.name == "Content-Length");
}, objUrlPattern, ["responseHeaders"])
```

Here, I am getting the content-length as undefined. I also checked the `obj --> responseHeader --> ...` and it's not showing the content-length.

Please advise as to what the issue is? Or maybe I am missing some configuration for `https://` links? Or is there any CORS related configuration required that I'm missing?

Comment: 1) Try adding 'extraHeaders' mode, see the documentation for more info. 2) Try case-insensitive compare e.g. x.name.toLowerCase() === "content-length"

Comment: actually i have tried with 'extraHeader' . but no luck . also i was checking the 
'obj' during debug. but not getting content-length.

Comment: Just in case, it's extraHeaders, not extraHeader.

Comment: yeah! tried extraHeaders. but still not working

Comment: please advise on this issue.

Comment: Not all responses have Content-Length header. Why do you think it should be present?

Comment: it's working fine if am running a web project locally & checking the content-length. 
but if i publish to IIS with SSL enabled . then it's not getting the Content-length

Comment: Use an external tool like Fiddler or Charles or Wireshark to inspect the real response and see if it has the header.